# Keyboard and mouse not working Win 8.1 X64 , SSD, asus mb

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, ssd, 64-bit, mouse

Following a critical win update 2 days ago, the mouse and keyboard no longer work on win 8.1, X64 with SSD though mouse and keyboard work in bios, i have tried the following:

I can get into the troubleshooting by hitting F8 on startup and selecting recovery disk

Recovery stick: no option to get into safe mode

Sys restore: will not restore - mssg anti virus needs to be disabled (obviously i cannot disable as mouse and keyboard do not work in win 8.1)

Refresh - will not verify recovery stick or win 8.1 install disk

Cannot figure out how to get to safe mode, tried bcedit from cmd prompt on recovery drive, x:windows\system32 as per web instructions however received mssg 
bc edit is not recognized......

seems like my only option is to reinstall, My data is safe as i save it to a separate drive, however i need to get the .pst mail file and a couple of other files off

Can anyone assist? Frustrated and need help, thanks.

Comment: In the recovery stick method once booted into it, try looking for troubleshoot > advanced options > startup settings > and choose enable safe mode. After reboot, choose enable safe mode.